# Need help to understand a math task about algebraic and parametric equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, parametric

Can anybody please explain this for me?:

Find the algebraic and parametric equations of the circle with centre (-2,3) that   passes  through (1,-1)

How do I find the algebraic and parametric equations of the circle?

Comment: What is the distance between $C(-2,3)$ and $P(1,-1)$? What is the distance between $C(-2,3)$ and any other point on the circumference of the circle (e.g. Q(x,y)) ?

Comment: By Pythagoras it is $$\sqrt{(-2-1)^2+(3--1)^2}$$ which is equal to 5 and is the radius of the circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  equation of a circle (algebraically) is given as

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$

where $a$ is the x coordinate of its centre, $b$ is the y coordinate of its centre and r is its radius.

Once you have input these values you can then convert this to a parametric form by simply substituting $x=r{sin}(t)$, $y=r{cos}(t)$.

Comment: so the parametric form will be: $$(rsin(t)-a)^2+(rcos(t)-b)^2=r^2$$

Comment: and the algebraic form is: $$(1+2)^2+(-1-3)^2=5^2$$

Comment: are the equations correct?

Comment: no the algebraic form should be $$(x+2)^2+(y-3)^2=5^2$$ and the parametric form is best found by rearranging this so it is equal to one, then picking your x and y values in such a manner that you end up with $$sin^2(t)+cos^2(t)=1$$

Comment: you only need to use the 1 and minus 1 to find the radius

Comment: try the substitution $x=5sin(t)-2$ and $y=5cos(t)+3$ giving the parametrization as $(5sin(t)-2,5cos(t)+3)$

Comment: Isn't the result: $$x=5sin(t)−2 $$ and $$y=5cos(t)+3$$?

Comment: Yes but generally its parametric form will be displayed as $(x,y)=(5sin(t)-2,5cos(t)+3)$ even though it is essentially the same as what you're suggesting

Answer (score 0):

Verify radius (5= R) with your work. Use standard form to start, then use $\sin, \cos $ for the two parts.

$$ R=5;\, (h,k)= (-2,3) \, ;$$

$$ x = h + R \cos\theta,\,y = k + R \sin\theta,\; 0< \theta< 2 \pi. $$

Please note there can be several parametric representations of the same algebraic equation as it is not unique, like:

$$ x = (h + R) \cos^2 \beta+ (h - R) \sin^2 \beta;,\,y = k+ R \cos \beta \sin \beta \,;\; 0< \beta<  \pi. $$

Comment: Have verified and yes it works with radius 5. What do you mean about using sin/cos for both parts? So I have to say x= x_0 + r * cos(phi) and y= y_0+ r * sin(rho) ? I don't have rho

Comment: Is it that the algebraic form is: $$(1+2)^2+(−1−3)^2=5^2$$

Comment: and the parametric form is: $$(rsin(t)+2)^2+(rcos(t)−3)^2=5^2$$

Comment: Are the equations correct?

Comment: You are confusing between parametric form and the equation. In the equation there is only one = sign. In a separate parametrized form, there are two = signs, two equations, one for each variable. Also  r and rho are same.

Comment: No, the equation representation is wrong. It is neither an algebraic equation nor is in parametric form